# API authentication for Ajax/Axios requests in a Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication

By default on Laravel the `api` middleware groups don't include the `StartSession` nor the `VerifyCsrfToken`. Instead it relies on the `auth:api` which expects an `api_token` value for each request.

In my case, the Vue frontend makes requests using Axios on the backend's API (`/api/...`). Since the user is logged in on the frontend it could simply use the same middlewares used for the `web` part.

How should I configure my `Kernel.php`/`$middlewareGroups`/`api` to use the API both with an `api_token` and the existing user session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep your Vue app component inside laravel app. This cares of keeping the session. Inside your layout's head you add [csrf token](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token):

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

If you use axios the documentation [says](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/js/bootstrap.js) it will be added automatically.

Api authentication with token is turned on by default(from what I remember). You have to make few more steps.

1. Add api_token column to users table, in migration, in model, in register controller or where you want to generate them.
2. Display api token inside Laravel's layout blade. It will mount apiToken to Laravel js object, for Vue to see it.

```
    <script>
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'apiToken' => auth()->user()->api_token ?? null,
        ]) !!};
    </script>
```

It might be questionable to display it in html, but since it's a monolithic app and you have to be logged in to connect your component with the api - it might be ok.

3. Add the following header to your axios setup

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + Laravel.apiToken;
```

I hope it will help you. If someone has something against such practices I would be happy to hear criticism. I don't like this way of printing php variables inside js script. Maybe there's more elegant solution.

EDIT:
there's also [Santcum](https://laravel.com/docs/master/sanctum) for easy api authentication

Comment: Si this means anybody can steal the api_key from the client’s browser and have full powers on the API from anywhere ?

Comment: If he won't be logged in he won't steal anything. I think so. It's just to communicate with the api

Comment: Or maybe store the token on login inside cookie